# Where curent opened chrome incognito window stores cookies (logined sesion)?

Tags: google-chrome, caching, cookies, google-chrome-devtools, incognito-mode

I have an curent opened incognito window that complet frozen(no respond, black screen, even exit buttons are dead) is there a easy or hardcore way to extract sesion cookies or cache to insert after pc reboot and continue a logined sesion?

*CONDITIONS*
Zero UI answer from chrome window. Probably a memory bug.
Chrome's built-in task manager opens but is white blank
*GOAL*
Save incognito cookies withowt using chrome window.
Needed a path on hard drive or a way to extract from RAM.

Comment: You'll have to dump process memory, load it in a debugger with pdb symbols for Chrome, then find where/how it stores the cookies in memory using Chromium's source code as reference.